# How to get File object to folder where from main class was loaded?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

```
package ru.reflection;
public class ReflectionTool {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    }
}
```

I am working in Intellij IDEA. The main class is located in
path_to_my_project/out/production/ru/reflection/Reflection.class

How can I get File object for folder where from Reflection.class was loaded - 
path_to_my_project/out/production/ru/reflection/
?

Comment: By "**main class**" you mean the `.class` file or the `.java` file?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou it is not the same question.

Comment: @Mike I mean .class file

Comment: @Alexey can you please clarify your question to show how it differs from the suggested duplicate.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Not a problem. The suggested answer there is - file:/C:/Users/Jon/Test/foo/Test.class. But I need a File object.

Comment: It is not always possible to get a File object - for example, if you use the "Build Project" option and then run the application from inside a .jar file.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou I don't run the application from inside a .jar file. By the way, I've got the correct answer below.